# cannot find numpy module and "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, numpy, pip, setup.py

I cloned the project from this site and tried to run it. https://github.com/sudhof/politeness/tree/python3

However after creating a virtual environment, when I run "pip install -r requirements", it shows

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Nasif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1o281esq\scipy\setup.py", line 165, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Nasif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1o281esq\scipy\setup.py", line 145, in setup_package
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Nasif\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1o281esq\scipy\
```

I have tried many solutions from the internet, but nothing seems to help. Any idea?

my python version 3.6.2
pip version 9.0.1

I also tried to install the requirements directly through pipenv, and shows the same result.

Comment: What happens when you try to import numpy in a Python interpreter? Also, how did you install Python (what source, etc)?

Comment: Numpy imports fine in the interpreter. I installed python through chocolatey in windows.